# LibreOffice: Draw shape (e.g., rectangle) on top of (say) pasted image

Tags: libre-office

I am new to LibreOffice. When I try to scribe out a rectangle shape or a text box, and the location is on top of a pasted image, I end up dragging the image instead.  On the odd occasion, some weird combination of keys allowed me to draw the desired object on top of the image, but I haven't been able to figure out the specific key combination that I typed to get this effect.  Surely this is something that is simple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LO allows at least texts to be sticked on images or other objects. Just have an image or a drawn shape selected and start to type something on it (click the Textbox  tool and type), the result will be a new combined object which contains the image and the text. The text stays editable. It can be deleted or cut, but it doesn't move independently.

To get independent text draw a textbox onto a empty space and start typing there. It can be dragged onto an image and edited there without losing the independence.

Other new objects than texts should not stick automatically to images. **To draw something on an image it must be deselected at first. Press Esc key before starting to draw.**

Comment: Thanks, user287001.  I highlighted the portion that directly addresses my question, though the rest of it is informative!